# Django Cannot assign "[<Store: Toby Pet Store>]":

Tags: django

I'm working an a pet store app.

The app displays all the pet stores and when you click on a pet store you see their's pet.

[image]

I created a form which allows users to add a store without no problem .:D

Now the problem is here . When I create a form for pet's owners to add their pet to their store.
I get this error .

I'm trying to let users create their pets and add it into their store instead of using the admin page.

```
Cannot assign "[<Store: John Pet Store>]": "Pet.owner" must be a "Store" instance.
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
C:\djcode\mysite\pet\views.py in fan
if form.is_valid():
```

My models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    number = models.BigIntegerField()
    address =models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Pet(models.Model):
    animal = models.CharField(max_length =20)
    description = models.TextField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.animal
```

My forms.py

```
from django import forms
from pet.models import Store
from pet.models import Pet
class StoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length =20,widget =forms.Textarea)
    number = forms.CharField(max_length =20,widget =forms.Textarea)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length = 20,widget = forms.Textarea)

    class Meta: 
        model = Store
        fields = ('name','number','address')

class PetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    animal =forms.CharField(max_length = 20,widget = forms.Textarea)
    description =forms.CharField(max_length =20, widget = forms.Textarea)
    owner = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Store.objects.all())
    image = forms.FileField()

    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = ('animal','description','owner','image')
```

My views.py

```
 from pet.models import Store , Pet
 from django.shortcuts import render_to_response ,get_object_or_404
 from pet.forms import StoreForm
 from django.template import RequestContext
 from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
 from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
 from pet.forms import PetForm

 def index(request):
    store = Store.objects.all()
    return render_to_response ('store.html',{'store':store})

 def brazil(request , animal_id):
     pets = Pet.objects.filter(owner_id=animal_id)
     return render_to_response ('animal.html',{'pets':pets})

 def create(request):
     form = StoreForm(request.POST or None)
     if form.is_valid():
         store = form.save(commit=False)
         store.save()
         if 'dog' in request.POST:
             dog = request.POST['next']
         else:
             dog = reverse('world:index')
         return HttpResponseRedirect(dog)
     return render_to_response(
         'creates.html',
         {'form':form},
         context_instance = RequestContext(request)
 )

 def fan(request):
     form = PetForm(request.POST or None)
     if form.is_valid():
         dad = form.save(commit=False)
         dad.save()
         if 'cat' in request.POST:
             cat = request.POST['next']
         else:
             cat = reverse('world:index')
         return HttpResponseRedirect(cat)
     return render_to_response(
         'fan.html',
         {'form':form},
         context_instance = RequestContext(request)
 )
```

My fan.html

```
 <form method="POST" "action">{% csrf_token %}
    <ul>
        {{ form.as_ul }}
    </ul>
    <input type = "submit" value= "Add Pets to Store" />
 </form>
```

Comment: I'm really sleep at the moment but must go on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is right here:

```
Cannot assign "[<Store: John Pet Store>]": "Pet.owner" must be a "Store" instance.
```

`[<Store: John Pet Store>]` isnt a `Store`, its an array containing `Store` objects (in your case just one).

in your pet form you have this line for owner:

```
owner = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Store.objects.all())
```

BUT you do not want owner to be a Multiple choice field, or else an array of owners are going to come back (whats going on right now).

you should change it to:

```
owner = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Store.objects.all())
```

#### EDIT from comment

```
class PetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = ('animal','description','owner','image')`
```

Comment: When I try to add an animal . It doesn't add one but ModelChoiceField created a dropbox

Comment: Do you reckon it's my image field?

Comment: i'm seeing something kinda wierd. if you are using `forms.ModelForm` you do not need to redefine your fields. It display the correct field widgets for your models. if that form isn't what you are expecting, you may have a modeling issue. your pet form could simply look like this (see edit)

Answer (score 2):

```
class StoreForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = Store

class PetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pet

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PetForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['owner'].queryset = Store.objects.all()


def create(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = StoreForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()

             if 'dog' in request.POST:
                 dog = request.POST['next']
             else:
                 dog = reverse('world:index')

             return HttpResponseRedirect(dog)
     return render_to_response(
         'creates.html',
         {'form':StoreForm()},
         context_instance = RequestContext(request)
 )

 def fan(request):
     form = PetForm()
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = PetForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()

             if 'cat' in request.POST:
                 cat = request.POST['next']
             else:
                 cat = reverse('world:index')

             return HttpResponseRedirect(cat)
     return render_to_response(
         'fan.html',
         {'form':form},
         context_instance = RequestContext(request)
 )
```

Comment: I still get this error ValueError at /pet/fan/ Cannot assign "[<Store: Toby Pet Store>]": "Pet.owner" must be a "Store" instance.

Comment: Is this typo error? <form method="POST" "action">{% csrf_token %}